# How to store and display the button names ( in different screens)that are clicked by user in android

Tags: android

In my app I have 4 screens(screen1,screen2,screen3,screen4)

Screen1 has 3 buttons(B1,B2,B3)
Screen2 has 3 buttons(B4,B5,B6)
Screen3 has 3 buttons(B7,B8,B9)

If a user clicks on any button in screen1 then screen2 is rendered. If a user clicks on any button in screen2 then screen3 is rendered.

My problem is:

In screen4 I have to display the button names that are clicked by user.

i.e If a User clicks on B2 in screen1 then clicks on B6 in screen2 then clicks on B7 in screen3, the output of screen4 should be:

B2

B6

B7

How can I do this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You basically need a combination of user1643999 and user370305's answers.

Answer (score 1):

Either Using `Intent putExtra()` to pass values to each Activity or Making [`Application Class`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) which holds the Values is the best option.

You can also use [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) but I think its make difficult to you..

**Update:**

Oh, I missed your question little, with **how to store**,

You can get button's name like, (only Example Actual may different)

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
String buttonName = button1.getText().toString().
```

Comment: only clicked button name need to be store and display in the final screen

Comment: how can i display the names in the screen4.

Comment: need only clicked button names

Comment: If a User clicks on B2 in screen1 then clicks on B6 in screen2 then clicks on B7 in screen3, the output of screen4 should be:

B2
B6
B7

Answer (score 0):

Better store the button name by String b1=button.getText().toString().a

Comment: how can i display the names in the screen4.